# How to select an object's class in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

How can I select an object's class in HQL? When I do the following:

```
select e.class, e.name from Entity e
```

Hibernate returns an Integer (e.g. [12, "name"]) instead of a class object. How can I return a Java class, or at least the class or entity name? Or, if this is not possible, how can I convert the 12 to a Java class?

For performance reasons, I can't query the full objects, i.e. I can't do

```
select e from Entity
```

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you are hibernate4, you can use HQL function 'type()' to get entity type

```
select type(e), e.name from Entity e
```

If you are hibernate3, the session.iterate() return entity as HibernateProxy with id only, and you can get entity name & id from it without initializing.

```
Iterator iterator = session.createQuery("from Entity e").iterate();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    HibernateProxy object = (HibernateProxy)iterator.next();
    System.out.println(object.getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier());
    System.out.println(object.getHibernateLazyInitializer().getEntityName());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can just use the addEntity() method to tell Hibernate to use your class to map the answer

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select e.class,e.name from Entity e where <your conditions>")
    .addEntity(Entity.class)
    List<Entity> result = query.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Scalar HQL which explicitly specifies the column name in the select clause will return a list of `object[]` .Each index in the returned array match the corresponding column in the select clause.

To return a list of object , use `select e from Entity e` or simply `from Entity` .

```
List<Entity> result =   (List<Entity>) session.createQuery("from Entity").list();
```

To restrict  the record returned by the HQL , apply some conditions in the where clause of the HQL, for example: `from Entity e where e.name = xxxxx`

Comment: Beat me to it :) When you've selected the entities, you can use the regular java getClass calls to know the returned class.

Comment: Hi, I can't do that, since I'm querying two gazillion records with 100s of different classes. The resulting query would be too slow.

Comment: can you apply some where clause in the HQL ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the **number of columns in the select list**,  you can us the `new` operator inside the `hql`.

That is,

```
select new Entity(e.class, e.name) from Entity e
```

Also, add a corresponding constructor in the `Entity` class that this query can use.

This will give you the `List<Entity>`, initialized with only 2 values.

This is helpful when you need a snapshot of a Large object in a performative way. Read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) for the API docs or [here](http://jyops.blogspot.in/2011/09/hibernate-data-fetching-options.html) for an example.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work with Class parameters. Leaving out the e.class works.

Comment: what is the corresponding the value for **Class** in DB? I hope it is a string, then you need to set the string and try to get the **class** from it.

Comment: It is a built-in property of Hibernate. E.g. in queries you can do `select e.name from Entity e where e.class = Person`. However `select e.class` will return an int, that I need to map to a class.